# How can I make this class display multiple bugs on the screen same time? (using array)

Tags: android-studio, 2d-games

I want to display multiple bugs how would i do this, i am a beginner and this is getting confusing with all the code. This could be done possibly with an array, like List.

It also supposed work in a way that the multiple bugs can have different speeds, which is shown below in the code by just subtracting a number from the bugs speed that is set.

This is one class from the program, this has rest of the classes for reference, https://www.daniweb.com/programming/threads/515921/android-programming-2d-game

```
package com.example.bugsmasher;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
public class Bug {
    // States of a Bug
    enum BugState {
        Dead,
        ComingBackToLife,
        Alive,              // in the game
        DrawDead,           // draw dead body on screen
    };
    BugState state;         // current state of bug
    int x,y;                // location on screen (in screen coordinates)
    double speed;           // speed of bug (in pixels per second)
    // All times are in seconds
    float timeToBirth;      // # seconds till birth
    float startBirthTimer;  // starting timestamp when decide to be born
    float deathTime;        // time of death
    float animateTimer;     // used to move and animate the bug
    // Bug starts not alive
    public Bug () {
        state = BugState.Dead;
    }
    // Bug birth processing
    public void birth (Canvas canvas) {
        // Bring a bug to life?
        if (state == BugState.Dead) {
            // Set it to coming alive
            state = BugState.ComingBackToLife;
            // Set a random number of seconds before it comes to life
            timeToBirth = (float)Math.random () * 5;
            // Note the current time
            startBirthTimer = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000f;
        }
        // Check if bug is alive yet
        else if (state == BugState.ComingBackToLife) {
            float curTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000f;
            // Has birth timer expired?
            if (curTime - startBirthTimer >= timeToBirth) {
                // If so, then bring bug to life
                state = BugState.Alive;
                // Set bug starting location at top of screen
                x = (int)(Math.random() * canvas.getWidth());
                // Keep entire bug on screen
                if (x < Assets.roach1.getWidth()/2)
                    x = Assets.roach1.getWidth()/2;
                else if (x > canvas.getWidth() - Assets.roach1.getWidth()/2)
                    x = canvas.getWidth() - Assets.roach1.getWidth()/2;
                y = 0;
                // Set speed of this bug
                speed = canvas.getHeight() / 4; // no faster than 1/4 a screen per second
                // subtract a random amount off of this so some bugs are a little slower
                // ADD CODE HERE
                // Record timestamp of this bug being born
                animateTimer = curTime;
            }
        }
    }
    // Bug movement processing
    public void move (Canvas canvas) {
        // Make sure this bug is alive
        if (state == BugState.Alive) {
            // Get elapsed time since last call here
            float curTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000f;
            float elapsedTime = curTime - animateTimer;
            animateTimer = curTime;
            // Compute the amount of pixels to move (vertically down the screen)
            y += (speed * elapsedTime);
            // Draw bug on screen
            canvas.drawBitmap(Assets.roach1, x-Assets.roach1.getWidth()/2,  y-Assets.roach1.getHeight()/2, null);
            // ADD CODE HERE - Draw each frame of animation as appropriate - don't just draw 1 frame
            // Has it reached the bottom of the screen?
            if (y >= canvas.getHeight()) {
                // Kill the bug
                state = BugState.Dead;
                // Subtract 1 life
                Assets.livesLeft--;
            }
        }
    }
    // Process touch to see if kills bug - return true if bug killed
    public boolean touched (Canvas canvas, int touchx, int touchy) {
        boolean touched = false;
        // Make sure this bug is alive
        if (state == BugState.Alive) {
            // Compute distance between touch and center of bug
            float dis = (float)(Math.sqrt ((touchx - x) * (touchx - x) + (touchy - y) * (touchy - y)));
            // Is this close enough for a kill?
            if (dis <= Assets.roach1.getWidth()*0.5f) {
                state = BugState.DrawDead;  // need to draw dead body on screen for a while
                touched = true;
                // Record time of death
                deathTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000f;
            }
        }
        return (touched);
    }
    // Draw dead bug body on screen, if needed
    public void drawDead (Canvas canvas) {
        if (state == BugState.DrawDead) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(Assets.roach3, x-Assets.roach1.getWidth()/2,  y-Assets.roach1.getHeight()/2, null);
            // Get time since death
            float curTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000f;
            float timeSinceDeath = curTime - deathTime;
            // Drawn dead body long enough (4 seconds) ?
            if (timeSinceDeath > 4)
                state = BugState.Dead;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A class is a variable type just like any other so you can have multiple variables of that type.  You could make an array but before that try just making one variable of this type and assigning values so that one bug shows up. Then when that works make a second variable of that type with different values so you get two bugs to show up.  Then when that works you can make an array.

Comment: can you provide an example?